# Why is my perl script slow on Windows 8.1, fine on 8.0 on same machine?

Tags: mysql, perl

I have an 600ish-line perl script, not written by me but used with permission, that parses a set of xml files and inserts them into a few MySQL tables.  I ran this script on my machine first back in May or so, and everything seemed fine; it was fast enough for my purposes (multiple insert queries per second), worked great.  I recently acquired more data that needed the same parsing, so I was going to run it again.  This time, it was *glacially* slow - 10-12 seconds per query.

No hardware changed in the interim; the only significant software change made was "upgrading" to Windows 8.1, when it was on 8.0 originally.  Could that be the cause of the problem? Anyone know how I might troubleshoot this?  At this pace, it's literally going to take three months to complete.

I'm happy to provide some/all of the script upon request, as well as any other details you might want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: has your database changed? check for triggers and indexes. try inserting one record manually

Comment: No indexes; other tables have been updated but no structural database changes; I don't know how to use a trigger, so no.  I'll try a manual insertion to these tables when I can (no access right now), but I will say that manually importing from .csv to other tables in the same db ran as fast as it ever has, and select queries run normal speed.

Comment: I don't think windows 8.1 can make perl script slow. may be it is the size of the XML file and the way the script is reading/parsing it.

Comment: I... don't understand enough about mysql/sql in general, I think.  I created a new schema, "created table[s] like" the ones being affected by this script, and ran it inserting into the new ones - and it's as quick as it used to be.  Thanks, bansi and @Joe Z - I appreciate the help, and this will take some investigative work on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To diagnose the performance problem in your script, consider installing and  using tools such as the following:

- [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-5.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm).  This excellent profiler toolkit will show you exactly where you're spending cycles executing Perl code.  By design, it *leaves out* time spent in I/O, including database calls.
- [`DBI::Profile`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.50/lib/DBI/Profile.pm).  This offers multiple levels of debug profiling, and can show you how long each database action takes.  It's an excellent companion to `Devel::NYTProf` and easy to use.

If *neither* `Devel::NYTProf` nor `DBI::Profile` show a hotspot in your code (either in a perl computation or a database query / transaction), then you should look through your code for `system` calls or network accesses to see if those are the culprits.